# Encouraging a 3-year-old's interest in minibeasts

Tags: toddler, activities

Our three-year-old son has always been interested in minibeasts, such as worms, ants, spiders, woodlice, snails, and slugs, but he now seems to be even more interested in them than ever. Whenever we bring him outside the house, he would ask to find some minibeasts.

We think that it is good to encourage this interest. What we have done so far is to visit nearby parks, fields, and woods, and find some minibeasts there to observe. We would mainly turn the rocks over to find worms and other small creatures underneath. But I would really like to hear new ideas for activities that we can do together with him, to encourage this interest.

Comment: Ant farm?  Worm farm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get him his own magnifying glass.

You can also find small plastic collecting jars with a lens built into the top for observing the contents.

[image]  [image]  [image]

Using a babyfood jar, and plastic tubing, and the toe of a women's stocking you can make a [great bug catcher](http://www.show.me.uk/site/make/Natural-World/ACT59.html).

As he gets older, spend your family TV time watching something worthwhile. My kids grew up watching "Uncle Dave" (David Attenborough) nature videos rather than reality/Disney/stupid TV. They're mostly on NetFlix.

Comment: I can't believe I forgot to include this: When you have a beastie, sit down together and go to this website http://www.whatsthatbug.com/